# Can't delete triples from Fuseki/Jena TDB

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I'm trying to do some simple deletes of triples in my TDB.  I'm trying to delete any triples that have a certain value, and any triples that link to it.  This is an example of one of the queries I'm running through Fuseki.

```
with <http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXX/>

delete {
  ?s2 ?p2 ?s .
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
where
{
  ?s2 ?p2 ?s .
  ?s ?p ?o .
  filter(strStarts(?o, "cPage")) .
}
```

I get this response:

## Success

Update succeeded

But no triples are actually removed.  I've checked that the --update flag is getting passed to Fuseki, but I can't figure out why nothing's happening.

Comment: Does the select query using the same where clause return values?

Comment: @user1209675 Right, are you sure that the WHERE part matches any result for the given graph? that be the first point to check. If yes, then it might be something with the read/write permissions of your Fuseki instance.

Comment: I have the same issue, my request with select returns the correct 12 triples.


switching for delete on the endpoint `update` says "Update succeeded".

but the previous select still returns the 12 triples :(

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem myself once. What I did wrong was to use the default endpoint: /datasetname/sparql (or /datasetname/query). These are read-only endpoints. If you want to insert or delete data, you can to use /datasetname/update as the enpoint.

See picture below: If you use the localhost webinterface, you can change the endpoint in the lower left.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the SPARQL UPDATE section of fuseki, type clear default.